# PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> my below scope works perfectly well in SQLite but in Postgres i get
>   the below error. I am unsure how to correct this in a PG format. could
>   one kindly advise me.

error:

```
PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "f"
2017-02-11T14:49:28.867872+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ..."."user_id" = $1 AND (subscription_payment_date = 'f' OR sub...
2017-02-11T14:49:28.867873+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2017-02-11T14:49:28.867874+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."user_id" = $1 AND (subscription_payment_date = 'f' OR subscription_payment_date IS NULL) AND (status = 'success')  ORDER BY created_at desc
```

payment.rb

```
scope :valid_payments, -> {where(['subscription_payment_date = ? OR subscription_payment_date IS ?', false, nil])}
```

schema:

```
  create_table "payments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "subscription_id"
    t.string   "stripe_payment_id"
    t.datetime "subscription_payment_date"
    t.string   "status"
  end
```

Comment: Well, timestamp can't have the value of `false`

Comment: so how would i state it if the timestamp/datetime is blank?

Comment: Isn't it `NULL` if it's not set in your table?